# How to run PHPscript in CPanel Cron job?

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to host and schedule my scripts in CPanel Cron job.
We have 2 scripts that power on and off Virtual Private Server.
I know there is a Wget command that runs them out of storage but can't remember how to write it.

I would love to get help with this issue.
Many thanks

```
PowerOn.php
PowerOff.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below cron job.

```
php -q PowerOn.php
php -q PowerOff.php
```

Make sure to give the full path to the file PowerOn.php and PowerOff.php and also set the time when the cron should run.

Comment: Error : Could not open input file: /public_html/CronJobs/Power_On.php

Comment: You may need do add full path to your script